# Adding keys to a json using an array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a basic json question that is giving me headache since a couple of hours, I am trying to dynamically add keys to a Json object using an array of string.

Here is my array of string:

```
let key =  ['session', 'view_state', 'footer', 'config', 'items']
```

I have another variable which is `jsonValue` and is my whole json object. I want to end up with one of those options:

```
jsonValue.session.view_state.footer.config.items
jsonValue['session']['view_state']['footer']['config']['items']
```

This is my best attempt using a `forEach`.

```
forEach(jsonKeys, (el) => {
  jsonCollection += jsonCollection !== undefined ? '."' +[el + '"'] : [ '"' + el + '"' ];
})
```

But I have this result:

```
undefined"session"."view_state"."footer"."config"."items"
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If it's `undefined`, you don't want to append.

Comment: need more code, not clearer enought

Comment: What is the end result you are after? How will you use this object stricture?
 Do you want `jsonValue.session.view_state.footer.config.items` to be a specific value? an object, an Array, something else?? Or are you trying to pass in the array to get at a specific value from your object?

Comment: I am trying to pass the array to get a specific value from my Json object, yes. Whether it is a  string on another array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To get a value using the keys array**

Iterate with Array#reduce, check the type of the current value, if it's an object, return the value of the key, if not return `undefined`:

```js
const obj = {
  "demo": true,
  "session": {
    "view_state": {
      "footer": {
        "config": {
          "items": [
            1,
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const keys =  ['session', 'view_state', 'footer', 'config', 'items'];

const value = keys.reduce((val, key) => val && typeof val === 'object' ?
  val[key] : undefind, obj);

console.log(value);
```

**To add a value using the `keys` array**

Use Array#reduceRight to create a chain of objects with the value you want. Use Object#assign to update the original object with the results:

```js
const keys =  ['session', 'view_state', 'footer', 'config', 'items'];

const obj = { demo: true };

Object.assign(obj, keys.reduceRight((val, key) => ({ [key]: val }), [1, 2])); // replace [1, 2] with the actual items

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Wow, `Array#reduceRight` .. what a fascinating bit of code. Nice answer!

Comment: very elegant solution ;-)

Comment: Short and neat! Thank you